# Sliding-window technique: How to move a window forward by more than one unit each time?

Tags: python

Now I am wondering how to move a window forward by 4 uints or other number of units instead of only one unit each time.
Could you please give me clues about it?

My code is like this:

```
import sys
INT_MIN = -sys.maxsize - 1
def maxSum(arr,n,k):
max_sum = INT_MIN
for i in range(n-k+1):
    current_sum = 0
    for j in range(k):
        current_sum = current_sum + arr[i+j]
    print(current_sum)
    max_sum = max(current_sum, max_sum)
return max_sum

arr = [1,4,2,10,2,3,1,0,20,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,5,1,4,5]
k = 4
n = len(arr)
```

Comment: Show at least some python code that we can comment on.

Comment: So in other words, you don't want a sliding window at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mostly have a correct answer already.
You wrote

```
for i in range(n - k + 1):
```

All that is needed is to specify a `step` of `k`:

```
for i in range(0, n - k + 1, k):
```

---

nit: this code

```
    current_sum = 0
    for j in range(k):
        current_sum = current_sum + arr[i + j]
```

could be written with slice notation as `current_sum = sum(arr[i:i + k])`.

---

Pandas offers [an implementation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) that might be of interest to you.